# Server 2008 32 bit Standard RDP issue

Tags: windows-server-2008

Am not able to take the RDP from my server. when try to **telnet the port : 3389,** Network connection refused error am getting. then check **netstat -a** the ports which are all listing the **3389**? there is nothing listing on list. read it some article  i have not seen the **Roles & Features** ---> not present Remote Desktop Services on the roles. then  i have checked in gpedit.msc-->administrator --> windows components--> RDP services are not present there also.

Help me out from this issue........ Looking your reply.

Thanks

Athick

Comment: Check your firewall setting, RDP may just be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

System control panel (sysdm.cpl) > Remote tab: select "Allow".

Answer (score 0):

From the Start menu right click on "Computer" and select "Properties".  On the left hand side there should be a column that has "Remote settings".  Click that and it should allow you to turn on Remote Desktop. If for some reason "Remote settings" isn't available, then you can click on "Advanced settings" and click on the "Remote" tab. There you can turn on Remote Desktop.